# Automatic email send/receive in Outlook

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-2013

Is there a way to set up Outlook (2013) to automatically send/receive emails when it is activated?
What you can do now is to intruct Outlook to periodically check the emails, and of course, it checks the emails at start time. That's fine, I am a fan... but most of the time Outlook runs minimized. Once I restore it (that is, bring Outlook in front), I would like it to perform an automatic sync, equivalent to pressing the Send/Receive Folders.
I agree this is not a critical issue at all, not even close, but for me it would make sense.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using `SendKeys` and send <kbd>F9</kbd> hotkey which performs the Send/Receive action. I would probably just do this keystroke myself, but you could programmatically attach to the `Explorer.Activate` event and generate this event as well. You can also add a debounce to control the frequency as to not overwhelm your Exchange server.

```cs
DateTime lastRun = DateTime.Now; // debouce control

void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Application.Explorers.NewExplorer += new Outlook.ExplorersEvents_NewExplorerEventHandler(explorers_NewExplorer);
}

void explorers_NewExplorer(Outlook.Explorer explorer)
{
    ((Outlook.ExplorerEvents_10_Event)explorer).Activate += new Outlook.ExplorerEvents_10_ActivateEventHandler(ExplorerWrapper_Activate);
}

void ExplorerWrapper_Activate()
{
    if ((DateTime.Now - lastRun).TotalMilliseconds > 500) // trigger limit 500ms
    {
        lastRun = DateTime.Now;
        System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send("{F9}"); // hotkey to send/receive
    }
 }
```

Comment: @SilverNinja cool, but I don't want to do anything programatically, I was just wondering if such a feature is already implemented in Outlook. Thank you

Comment: If you are not looking for a programmatic solution, then this question is off-topic.  Stack Overflow is for *programming* questions.

Comment: or maybe there can be set some Macro to do it?